# Compare data progress in percentage with past version in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, compare, data-analysis

Hi I have a table with data that is the progress on percentage, but every few days the progress is change so I would like to compare this with a formula this is my table:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12seJVgwCmlFJWVj0LQncR_euJlXDi0ATRca7xIY0WB0/edit?usp=sharing

```
ID  Management  Radiology   Nuclear Pathology   Laboratorie Systemic    Pediatric   Radiotherapy
208 0.0%        0.0%        75.5%   0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        94.1%    
209 69.3%      95.4%        71.0%   21.0%       0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        72.2%
```

Then I need to compare sometime 3 or 4 tables to check if the progress have been increased or decreased. I would like some help with a formula to compare all the tables and have an output like this:
In the past table for ID 209 there is a progress now the completness is 84.8% for pathology
So my output will be a similar table with something like +63.8 which is the difference or in case that is less progress -23. I'll leave this desired output in the format that I want in the sheet output. help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think having different sheets, each corresponding to the progress on a given date, is not the best approach here.

It would be preferable to have a single table in one sheet with an additional date column alongside indicating the progress percentages for each ID & department on that date; you would then be able to use a simple QUERY to determine if there had been any progress between two dates for a given ID/department.

Comment: and for that could you share a formula?